# Scala pattern matching with function arguments

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I am a newbie in scala. I am trying to understand below lines of code:-

```
val word = "f"
val file = "resources/abc.dat"

val func: (String) => String = word match {
     case "f" => first
     case "s" => second
     case "t" => third
     case _ => default
}

def first(file: String) : String = {
     println("First" + file)
     "first"
}

def second(file: String) : String = {
     println("Second" + file)
     "second"
}

def default(file: String) : String = {
     println("Default" + file)
     "default"
}
```

---

What I understand so far is in func, word is matched with cases and particular function is called.But I don't understand how arguments are passed to each function call.

Any pointers will be of great help to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you are NOT calling function in your pattern matching, you are just RETURNING a function , indeed the type of `func` is `(String) => String`, which you can abbreviate in `String=>String`.

You could then call it like `func("ABCDE")`.

See [this](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html) for a brief explanation on Scala types

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification.I am able to understand the flow now.